# Dynamically create dataTable for PieChart with Google Charts in Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to visualize some data in Ionic/Angular with a pie-chart. It's for a project for university. 
In my app.module.ts I'm importing 
    `import { Ng2GoogleChartsModule } from 'ng2-google-charts';`
And in my statistics.page.ts I have this method:

```
createChart() {
if (this.stats.length > 0) { this.hasStats = true; }
this.pieChartData = {
  chartType: 'PieChart',
  dataTable: this.stats,
  options: {
    title: 'Ausgaben',
    width: 400,
    height: 300
  }
};
```

}

stats is defined as:

```
stats: [string, number] [] = [];
```

and filled with the data I want to display.
When I compile the app, I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unknown header type: 102
```

I'm fairly new to Angular/Ionic and all solutions I found were for Javascript embedded in HTML code. But I have to use Angular modules. I just can't get it to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add an array for the columns headings to `stats`

*ng2-google-charts* uses the following method to create the data table.

[`arrayToDataTable()`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable)

this method expects the first array element in the data array to be column headings.
`[string, string]`

for example, a valid data array might contain...

```
[
  ['Column 1', 'Column 2'],
  ['First Row', 15000000],
  ['Second Row', 20000000]
]
```

`arrayToDataTable` method does have an argument for --> `firstRowIsData`
setting this to `true` would also resolve the issue.

however, to do so would require modifying the *ng2-google-charts* code

Comment: Thanks, this helps alot. But my stats array is of type [string, number], how can I add a leading element of type [string, string] to this array?

Comment: found a solution, i just changed it to type [any, any]. SOLVED, Thanks!